# How to fix 500 (Internal Server Error) Vue js - Laravel (Edited)

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Im doing a project using Vuejs and laravel for the university and i want support when i send the information to the api

Im using axios to do the post but they give a me a error: 500 (Internal Server Error). But i cant see the error, i think i have all good in my code.

This is my submit method

```
submitFiles() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
        if (this.files[i].id) {
          continue;
        }
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", this.files[i]);

        axios
          .post("/files/upload-file", formData, {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }
          })
          .then(
            function(data) {
              this.files[i].id = data["data"]["id"];
              this.files.splice(i, 1, this.files[i]);
              console.log("success");
            }.bind(this)
          )
          .catch(function(data) {
            console.log("error");
          });
      }
    }
  }
```

This is my route post(Edited)

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});



Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('files', 'FileEntriesController@index');
});

Route::get('files/create', 'FileEntriesController@create');
Route::post('files/upload-file', 'FileEntriesController@uploadFile');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('{path}','HomeController@index')->where('path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?');
```

And this is my controller

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request) {
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $path = hash( 'sha256', time());

        if(Storage::disk('uploads')->put($path.'/'.$filename,  File::get($file))) {
            // $input['user_id'] = $user_id;
            $input['filename'] = $filename;
            $input['mime'] = $file->getClientMimeType();
            $input['path'] = $path;
            $input['size'] = $file->getClientSize();
            $file = FileEntry::create($input);

            return response()->json([
                'success' => true,
                'id' => $file->id
            ], 200);
        }
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false
        ], 500);
    }
```

I expected to past the information to the database but it show me the error 405 (Method Not Allowed)

EDITED

In ispect option in the section network i can find this:

{message: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found",…}
exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"
file: "C:\laragon\www\vue-laravel-app\app\Http\Controllers\FileEntriesController.php"
line: 11
message: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Input' not found"

Comment: What does the rest of your routes file look like. Do you have something like `Route::get('files/{file}', 'FileEntriesController@show');` above the upload route? Everything you posted looks correct.

Comment: i edited my post and you can see all my routes and that routes is on web.php file

Comment: what is the value of ```this.post_url``` and can you set the url in axios to '/files/upload-file' just to see if that works.

Comment: Make sure you created a route entry using Route::post() for the  `post_url`you are sending

Comment: /files/upload-file/ i try this but it didnt work

Comment: I can think of one more thing. Can you move your upload file post route to be above ```Auth::routes()```

Comment: i try it and do the same error

Comment: What is the value of `this.post_url`. You never answered when @DinoNumić asked, and I think that might be part of your issue. It looks like it's matching your `Route::get('{path}','HomeController@index')->where('path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?');` route, and throwing the 405.

Comment: okay i put again /files/upload-file and the error change to the 500  (Internal Server Error)

Comment: and the value this.post-url must be the same of the  files/uplodad-file

Comment: Are there any errors in the log?

Comment: no error in the log

Comment: add `use Input;` at the top of the file to get rid of the error you edited.

Answer (score 1):

All POST/PUT/PATCH requests in `web.php` are protected with `CSRF-protection`.

You seem to be not passing any token with your request headers or may be is it in the body? if not it'll result in `Method Not Allowed` error.

It would be better idea to use API routes for it as `csrf-protection` is disabled on them.

Comment: The default Laravel setup configures axios to get the csrf token from a meta tag in the default layout. If this were related to a CSRF token mismatch I would expect to see an HTTP 419 response anyway (due to a TokenMismatchException).